# What is the correct way to iterate through multidimensional arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I am currently trying to get a deeper understanding of how to use arrays, and I am not sure how to keep track of the position of the array. I want to know how to take information for this data format and they be able to use that information.

Below is just an example I've created to demonstrate my confusion. If anyone could either show me an example of how to **correctly** navigate multidimensional arrays, or elaborate with some knowledge I would greatly appreciate it.

I seem to be stuck with simple arrays.

```
static int largerNum(int a, int b) 
{
    if (a > b) 
    {
        return a;
    } else 
    {
        return b;
    }
}

//two dimentional array 
int[][] numArr = {
    { 10, 20 }, 
    { 5,  3  }, 
    { 4,  4  } 
};

int ans1 = 0;
int ans2 = 0;

//iterate through first compartment of array
for (int i = 0; i < numArr.length; i++) 
{
    //how i am currently tracking inner arrays
    int rotation = 1;

    //iterate through second compartment of array within first array
    for (int j = 0; j < numArr[i].length; j++) 
    {
        if (rotation == 1) 
        {
            ans1 = numArr[i][j];
            rotation++;
        } 
        else if (rotation == 2) 
        {
            ans2 = numArr[i][j];
            rotation--;
        } else 
        {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }
    System.out.println(largerNum(ans1, ans2));
}
```

Comment: Your iteration seems fine at first glance. What problem are you facing?

Comment: You may want to explain what you want the code you posted to do, because it runs just fine as is (if you stick that in a method, of course), so any attempt at explaining where you went wrong would be pure speculation on our part.

Comment: Where I'm using the variable "rotation", is there not a more appropriate way to accurately traverse an array with an indifinitive size?

Comment: I improved the code formatting (please don't discuss the braces, my method of indentation is for educational purposes only) and improved the title to 'multidimensional'.